# collection to Datatable and dataset

Tags: c#

i work on C# vs05 ...

```
DataTable dt=CreateTable(_oGeneralReports);//collection _oGeneralReports
```

i want a method that Converting a Collection into a DataTable ..dt contain the collection value.....help me to get this

Comment: what's the return value from this:
CreateTable(_oGeneralReports);

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a new data table and manually add all the columns to it, then loop through the collection adding each item to the table. e.g

```
public DataTable CreateTable(ICollection items)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));

    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["Column1"] = item.Column1;
        row["Column2"] = item.Column2;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .....i want to avoid bellow lines how :
table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));

Comment: Ah. You probably want to use reflection then. This article (http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a0beac5f-c952-4ef9-b192-f919f2bd6a46/converting-a-collection-i.aspx) seems to do it quite nicely.